# Why I cant make this SVG draw when scrolling down? Im using skrollr

Tags: jquery, skrollr

Firt post here.

I followed an example from skrollr (jquery), where you can draw SVG paths when scrolling down

http://www.denissemiranda.com/test/path.html

The problem is that it works for the first SVG and the first ones I copy-pasted (now at the bottom), but now when I try to change any of them the scroll thing dont work, like the second part of the site. I dont know what Im doing wrong.

Im using it combined with superscrollorama to fade the text (maybe is not the best solution but Im still learning)

Thank you !!!

example

This works
´

```
    <div class="bloque1">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="200px" height="200px">
                <path
                    style="fill:none;stroke:#fff;stroke-width:5;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:6000;stroke-dashoffset:0"
                    data-0="stroke-dashoffset:6000;" data-end="stroke-dashoffset:0;"

                    d="M74,102.2c8.3-1.9,16.5-3.5,25-3.7c9.3-0.2,18.4,1.7,27.6,3.7
                    c-0.3,2.2-0.5,4.3-0.8,6.3c-0.9,7.3-1.9,14.7-2.7,22c-0.1,1.2-0.5,2-1.6,2.6c-3,1.9-6,4-9,6c-0.7,0.5-1,1-1,1.8
                    c0,8,0,16.1,0,24.1c0,0.8-0.3,1.3-1,1.6c-2.7,1.4-5.5,2.6-8.6,3c-3.4,0.4-6.6-0.4-9.7-1.9c-3.4-1.6-3.3-1.6-3.3-5.4
                    c0-7.2,0-14.4,0-21.6c0-0.8-0.3-1.3-0.9-1.7c-3.2-2.1-6.4-4.2-9.6-6.4c-0.4-0.3-0.9-0.9-0.9-1.5c-0.9-7.3-1.8-14.5-2.7-21.8
                    C74.6,107.2,74.3,104.8,74,102.2z"
                />

                <path
                    style="fill:none;stroke:#fff;stroke-width:5;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:6000;stroke-dashoffset:0"
                    data-0="stroke-dashoffset:6000;" data-end="stroke-dashoffset:0;"

                    d="M119.1,75.9c0,10.2-8.4,18.7-18.7,18.8
                    C90.1,94.7,81.5,86.2,81.5,76c0-10.5,8.5-18.9,18.9-18.9C110.6,57.1,119.1,65.6,119.1,75.9z"
                />

                <path
                    style="fill:none;stroke:#fff;stroke-width:5;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:6000;stroke-dashoffset:0"
                    data-0="stroke-dashoffset:6000;" data-end="stroke-dashoffset:0;"

                    d="M51.6,102.2c6-1.8,12.1-3.2,18.6-3.7c0.3,2.7,0.6,5.4,0.9,8
                    c0.8,6.8,1.5,13.7,2.3,20.5c0.2,1.5,0.3,3,0.5,4.4c0.1,0.5,0.4,1,0.8,1.3c2,1.4,4,2.7,6,4.1c0.4,0.3,0.7,0.8,0.7,1.3
                    c0,6.5,0,13.1,0,19.6c0,0.4-0.2,1-0.5,1.2c-1.9,1-3.8,2.1-5.9,2.9c-3.2,1.2-6.2,0.2-9.1-1.3c-3.2-1.7-3.2-1.7-3.2-5.3
                    c0-6.1,0-12.3,0-18.4c0-0.5-0.3-1-0.6-1.4c-2-2-4-4-5.9-6c-0.5-0.6-1-1.4-1.1-2.1c-1.2-8.2-2.4-16.5-3.6-24.7
                    C51.5,102.5,51.5,102.4,51.6,102.2z"
                />
                <path
                    style="fill:none;stroke:#fff;stroke-width:5;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:6000;stroke-dashoffset:0"
                    data-0="stroke-dashoffset:6000;" data-end="stroke-dashoffset:0;"

                    d="M83.5,91.1c-5.3,4.8-13.9,4.7-19.5-0.3c-5.7-5.1-6.6-13.7-2.2-19.9
                    c4.7-6.5,13.1-7.5,18.1-4.9C76.1,75.1,77.2,83.4,83.5,91.1z"
                />
                <path
                    style="fill:none;stroke:#fff;stroke-width:5;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:6000;stroke-dashoffset:0"
                    data-0="stroke-dashoffset:6000;" data-end="stroke-dashoffset:0;"

                    d="M130.5,98.7c5,1.3,9.9,2.6,14.9,3.9c-0.3,2.6-0.5,4.9-0.8,7.2
                    c-0.7,6.1-1.4,12.1-2,18.2c-0.1,0.8-0.4,1.4-1,2c-2.2,1.7-4.3,3.5-6.5,5.3c-0.8,0.6-1,1.2-1,2.2c0,6.7,0,13.4,0,20.1
                    c0,0.9-0.2,1.4-1,1.8c-2.2,1-4.3,2.1-6.5,2.8c-2.8,0.8-5.5-0.2-8-1.5c-3.2-1.7-3.2-1.7-3.2-5.3c0-4.7,0-9.5,0-14.2
                    c0-0.9,0.2-1.4,1-1.9c3.1-2,6.1-4.1,9.2-6.1c0.8-0.5,1.2-1.1,1.3-2c0.6-5.9,1.3-11.7,1.9-17.6c0.5-4.5,1-8.9,1.5-13.4
                    C130.3,99.7,130.4,99.4,130.5,98.7z"
                />
                <path
                    style="fill:none;stroke:#fff;stroke-width:5;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:6000;stroke-dashoffset:0"
                    data-0="stroke-dashoffset:6000;" data-end="stroke-dashoffset:0;"

                    d="M117.1,91.1c6.3-7.7,7.4-16,3.6-25.1c4.6-2.6,12.9-1.8,17.7,4.3
                    c4.7,6,4.1,14.9-1.4,20.1C131.4,95.7,122.6,96,117.1,91.1z"
                />
                <path
                    style="fill:none;stroke:#fff;stroke-width:5;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:6000;stroke-dashoffset:0"
                    data-0="stroke-dashoffset:6000;" data-end="stroke-dashoffset:0;"

                    d="M185.9,59.7c0,2.8-2.2,5-5,5h-35.5l-4.5,3.2l0-3.2h-2.8
            c-2.8,0-5-2.2-5-5V48.4c0-2.8,2.2-5,5-5h42.8c2.8,0,5,2.2,5,5V59.7z"
                />

                <path
                    style="fill:none;stroke:#fff;stroke-width:5;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:6000;stroke-dashoffset:0"
                    data-0="stroke-dashoffset:6000;" data-end="stroke-dashoffset:0;"

                    d="M15.7,59.6c0,2.8,2.2,5,5,5h35.5l4.5,3.2l0-3.2h2.8c2.8,0,5-2.2,5-5
            V48.3c0-2.8-2.2-5-5-5H20.7c-2.8,0-5,2.2-5,5V59.6z"
                />

                <path
                    style="fill:none;stroke:#fff;stroke-width:5;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:6000;stroke-dashoffset:0"
                    data-0="stroke-dashoffset:6000;" data-end="stroke-dashoffset:0;"

                    d="M126.7,46.4c0,2.8-2.2,5-5,5h-19.1l-2.2,3.2L98,51.4H78.9
            c-2.8,0-5-2.2-5-5V35.2c0-2.8,2.2-5,5-5h42.7c2.8,0,5,2.2,5,5V46.4z"
                />
        </svg>
<h2 id="fade-it"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur <b>adipisicing elit</b>
        </div> <!--end of bloque1 div-->
```

And this one is not working. The only difference is the path, But even if I copy the path from above, it fails to animate when scrolling down.

```
<div class="bloque2">
             <h2 id="fade-it1"> <b>¿De qué sirven si carecen de emoción?</b></h2> 
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="300px" height="300px">
            <path
                style="fill:none;stroke:#fff;stroke-width:5;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:6000;stroke-dashoffset:0"
                data-0="stroke-dashoffset:6000;" data-end="stroke-dashoffset:0;"

                d="M240.9,102.4c-3.5-8.3-8.8-15.3-15.8-20.9c-8-6.4-17.1-10.1-27.1-11.1
    c-6.5-0.6-13,0-19.3,1.9c-11,3.3-20,9.7-27,19.1c-0.6,0.9-1.3,1.8-2,2.8c-8-11.5-18.5-19.1-31.9-22c-13.4-3-26-0.7-37.8,6.4
    c0.2,0.4,0.4,0.7,0.5,0.9c-1-0.9-1.7-0.2-2.4,0.4c-0.9,0.7-1.9,1.2-2.7,2c-2.3,2-4.6,4.1-6.7,6.3c-3.8,4-6.8,8.7-9.1,13.7
    c-2.4,5.3-3.9,10.9-4.6,16.8c-0.8,7,0,13.8,2.1,20.4c2.3,7,5.4,13.5,9.1,19.8c5.7,9.6,12.6,18.4,20.1,26.6
    c7.9,8.6,16.6,16.4,25.8,23.5c11.9,9.1,24.5,17,37.9,23.4c0.3,0.2,0.9,0.1,1.2,0c2.5-1.4,5-2.9,7.5-4.4
    c14.6-8.7,28.4-18.7,41.1-30.2c11.4-10.3,21.8-21.6,30.4-34.5c4.7-7,8.7-14.4,11.6-22.5c1.7-4.7,2.9-9.5,3.2-14.5
    C245.6,118,244.1,110,240.9,102.4z M156.8,145.3l0.2,28l-13.3,0.1l-0.2-28c-3-2.1-5-5.6-5.1-9.5c0-6.4,5.1-11.7,11.6-11.8
    c6.4,0,11.7,5.1,11.8,11.6C161.8,139.7,159.8,143.2,156.8,145.3z"
            />
        </svg>
        </div><!--endofbloque2 div-->
```

Comment: Perhaps post an example of your code that contains the problem? That would make it easier to tell what the problem is.

Comment: The problem is that I dont see whats wrong in the code :/ the first SVG works perfectly and the second one is written almost the same but it doesnt work. I would like to know what Im missing.

Answer (score 0):

IF anyone is interested, the solution to this is to adjust the stroke-dasharray and the stroke-dashoffset to the length of each path. –

Thanks to Alexander Prinzhorn, creator of skrollr.